# Ion Koush Library - Response is not cacheable

Tags: android, android-ion

I'm trying to get some jsons from my backend API using Ion Koush Library.
I could do it with sucess in one of the API routes, but at the other I'm having the following answer : Response is not cacheable. For a better understanding of the problem here is the code:

```
  Ion.with(clientSummaryActivity.this)
      .load("GET",url)
      .setLogging("LOG",Log.VERBOSE)
      .addQuery("format","json")
      .setHeader("Authorization",getIntent().getExtras().getString("token"))
      .asJsonArray()
      .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonArray>() {
          @Override
          public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonArray result) {
              // do stuff with the result or error
              if(e != null){
                  Toast.makeText(clientSummaryActivity.this, "Erro na Query: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //cria balao de texto na view indicada
                  Log.v("Query Error2: ",""+e);
                  return;
              }
              if(result == null)
                  Log.v("Error: ","resultado vazio");
              else
                   Log.v("Teste: ",""+result);
              return;
          }
      });
  }
```

And here is the debug log:

```
> D/LOG: (0 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: preparing request

>D/LOG: (0 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: preparing request

>I/LOG: (0 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: Using loader: com.koushikdutta.ion.loader.HttpLoader@18cbec99

>D/LOG: (0 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: Executing request.

>V/LOG: (4 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: Resolving domain and connecting to all available addresses

>V/LOG: (10 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: attempting connection to /10.0.2.2:8080

>V/LOG: (14 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: socket connected

>V/LOG: (14 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: 
GET /api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.2.2:8080
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; Android SDK built for x86_64 Build/LMY48X)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Token a3e8b50ae73aabad0605433f704eb628269f68c8

>V/LOG: (16 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: request completed

>W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fca6d3b8380, error=EGL_SUCCESS

>D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7fca6d1e4c00 (ListView) with handle 0x7fca6406c080

>V/LOG: (433 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: Received headers:

>       HTTP/1.0 200 OK

>       Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2017 13:28:12 GMT

>       Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.12

>       Vary: Accept

>       X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

>       Content-Type: application/json

>       Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS

>D/LOG: (433 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: Response is not cacheable
>V/LOG: (433 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: Final (post cache response) headers:

>       HTTP/1.0 200 OK

>       Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2017 13:28:12 GMT

>       Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.12

>       Vary: Accept

>       X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

>       Content-Type: application/json

>       Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS

>D/LOG: (433 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: Connection successful

>V/LOG: (434 ms) http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/comentario/cliente/00013436415782/?format=json: closing out socket (exception)
```

And here is the Json acquired by a browser REST client:

```
  {
    "id_comentario": 5,
    "id_venda_vendas": {
      "id_venda": 139,
      "id_cliente_cliente": {
        "id_cliente": 22,
        "nome": "nome",
        "telefone": "nao_tem_ainda_layout",
        "cpf": "cpf",
        "endereco": "endereco",
        "primeira_vez": true,
        "data_nascimento": "dob",
        "observacao": null,
        "foto": null,
        "email": "nao_tem_ainda_layout",
        "id_ultima_compra": {}
      },
      "id_loja_loja": {
        "id_loja": 2,
        "nome": "nome",
        "nome_fantasia": "nomefantasia",
        "cnpj": "cnpj"
      },
      "data": "2016-11-18",
      "hora": "15:36:02"
    },
    "id_funcionario_funcionario": {
      "id_funcionario": 2,
      "nome": "nome",
      "cargo": "cargo"
    },
    "id_tipo_comentario_tipo_comentario": {
      "id_tipo_comentario": 2,
      "tipo": "Tipo"
    },
    "descricao": "nao tem descricao"
  }
]
```

The point is, why I can get it from the REST client and Ion says that Response is not cacheable? And what does it mean?

OBS: I can get successful results from other query. But since the post is too long I'll not post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Ion automatically cache all `GET` requests. And your server, as i see, sends header `Cache-Control: no-cache`, means that this request is not allowed to be cached. You can change your cache policy on server or add `.noCache()` to your request.

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for the answer.
I've already tried this solution but with no success. Just to confirm, this setting is made at ion.with, right?
Also, here's the debug log:

http://pastebin.com/w7JNHiYh

I'm looking how I can set Headers in Django RestFramework, maybe I can solve this way.

Comment: Hi I solved it, I don't no why .noCache() it is not working for me so I used:
        Ion.getDefault(getApplicationContext()).configure().getResponseCache().setCaching(false);

And now everything it is OK. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Orest Savchak I could solve it using:

```
    Ion.getDefault(getApplicationContext()).configure().getResponseCache().setCaching(false);
```

For more reading, check:

https://github.com/koush/ion/issues/228